# How to format telephone (i.e. xxx-xxx-xxxx) in vuejs with <b-input > tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I want to enable text box to take formatting while tying telephone number into textbox.

Comment: Please provide an example code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the question doesn't have a lot of information on what has been tried or how to achieve it I'll just make a common component that you can reuse for later.

What you can do it with a watcher and a regexp on the field that formats the number to what you want to display

```js
Vue.component('my-phone-input', {
    template: `
        <div>
            <input type="text" v-model="formattedPhoneValue" @keyup="focusOut" @blur="focusOut"/>
        </div>`,
    data: function() {
        return {
            phoneValue: 0,
            formattedPhoneValue: "0",
            preventNextIteration: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        focusOut: function(event) {
            if (['Arrow', 'Backspace', 'Shift'].includes(event.key)) {
              this.preventNextIteration = true;
                return;
            }
            if (this.preventNextIteration) {
              this.preventNextIteration = false;
              return;
            }
            this.phoneValue = this.formattedPhoneValue.replace(/-/g, '').match(/(\d{1,10})/g)[0];

      // Format display value based on calculated currencyValue
            this.formattedPhoneValue = this.phoneValue.replace(/(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})(\d{1,4})/g, '$1-$2-$3');
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <my-phone-input></my-phone-input>
</div>
```

Comment: It should apply formatting with in the text box while we type into it.

Comment: Done, do you want to try it out now?